# The user license doesn't allow the permission: Manage Custom Report Types

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I want users to create custom Report Type and Reports for which I have given  **Manage Custom Report Types** permission along with other Permissions in a permission set. When I am trying to assign it to a user of Salesforce Platform license, I am getting below error.

**The user license doesn't allow the permission: Manage Custom Report Types**

Please assist how I can resolve this so that users can create report types as well

Answer (score 2):

Well, if SFDC says you can't assign that permission to a user w/ Standard Platform License then you can't. There's a reason why [Standard Platform Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=5) are cheaper as they give lesser functionality.

> Designed for users who need access to custom apps but not to standard CRM functionality. Users with this user license are entitled to use custom apps developed in your organization or installed from Salesforce AppExchange. In addition, they are entitled to use core platform functionality such as accounts, contacts, reports, dashboards, documents, and custom tabs. These users are not entitled to some user permissions and standard apps, including report subscriptions and standard tabs and objects such as forecasts, leads, campaigns, and opportunities. Users with this license can also use Connect Offline.

Your only workaround is to upgrade those users to a regular user license or delegate the work of CRT to a user who has the requisite permission.